# Bottom of div transparent (including contain of div)

Tags: css, wordpress

I need to make a bottom of div transparent / covered with black-transparent gradient, but the problem is, that I need to cover or make transparent as well the content of div.

Something like here, but the blue gradient has to be in the top layer, not background http://jsfiddle.net/etienne_carre/GEkFn/

The problem is, that is for WordPress template for generated content, so I don't know how many and what type they will be. You can see [page here](http://demo.kybernaut.cz/zvratenyhumor/), it's for `<div class = "article">` which is in `<div class = "post">` and it's genereted for every post. If you can do it with some plugin, I can use it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem with putting div/p under the div.article which has gradient background and if necessary (there is "show more options" active) it's displayed and moved with css position: relative bit up to the top.